# Existing library/algorithm for episodic frequency detection and prediction in a time series?

Tags: python, algorithm, rss, frequency, time-frequency

I'm working with podcast RSS feeds in Python. Are there any existing libraries or algorithms to detect and predict periodic release schedules, given a series in time?

For example, if five items in [an RSS feed](https://feeds.feedburner.com/rocketjump/story-break) had the following timestamps:

```sh
Fri, 20 Nov 2020 02:16:14 +0000
Fri, 13 Nov 2020 17:51:58 +0000
Fri, 6 Nov 2020 03:08:04 +0000
Fri, 30 Oct 2020 19:09:29 +0000
Fri, 23 Oct 2020 01:23:10 +0000
```

is there an algorithm to determine "Weekly on Fridays"? Or if [they](https://feeds.megaphone.fm/vergecast) were:

```sh
Tue, 24 Nov 2020 10:00:00 -0000
Fri, 20 Nov 2020 09:00:00 -0000
Tue, 17 Nov 2020 10:00:00 -0000
Fri, 13 Nov 2020 10:00:00 -0000
Tue, 10 Nov 2020 10:00:00 -0000
```

to determine "Twice a week, next episode Friday the 27th"? I believe [Pocket Casts](https://www.pocketcasts.com/) has a feature like this, but it remains proprietary.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy ones you can use `pd.infer_freq` in this way

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

date_range = [
    "Fri, 20 Nov 2020",
    "Fri, 13 Nov 2020",
    "Fri, 6 Nov 2020",
    "Fri, 30 Oct 2020",
    "Fri, 23 Oct 2020"]

date_range_2 = [
    "Tue, 24 Nov 2020",
    "Fri, 20 Nov 2020",
    "Tue, 17 Nov 2020",
    "Fri, 13 Nov 2020",
    "Tue, 10 Nov 2020"]

def get_frequency(date_range):
    ts = pd.Series(index=date_range)
    return pd.infer_freq(ts.index)

print(f"First Time Series: {get_frequency(date_range)}")
print(f"Second Time Series: {get_frequency(date_range_2)}")
```

Giving you no output for the second, but for the first one

```
First Time Series: -1W-FRI
Second Time Series: None
```

Comment: `pandas` sounds interesting, I'll check it out! Thanks!